# Fix BSOD after VeraCrypt Rescue Disk decryption and boot rebuild

Tags: windows, boot, encryption, bsod, veracrypt

So my laptop's motherboard died a little while ago, and once I replaced it, my full-disk-encrypted Windows installation gave me the 0xc000000e error code: "Required device missing"

So, I use my VeraCrypt Rescue Disk to permanently decrypt the system partition. Then, I use a Windows installation disk in recovery mode to delete everything in the boot partition, and rebuild it with `bcdboot C:\Windows /s B:`, which completes successfully. Now that I reboot, I get a bluescreen caused by `veracrypt.sys` with the `SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` error.

Upon booting into Safe Mode, Windows restores the VeraCrypt bootloader, and the bluescreen still occurs.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try booting in safe mode?

Comment: @Bodo Yes. When I did, the laptop rebooted multiple times, threw me back into the VeraCrypt bootloader, and upon skipping its prompts, threw me into the same BSOD again.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification.

Comment: If the problem is the Veracrypt system file, it seems like a simple case of ensuring the system file is NOT loaded.  This should be perfectly safe to do if Veracrypt no longer encrypts the device. You should be able to boot Safe Mode and specifically NOT load that particular system file.  How you accomplish that is more difficult. It appears the driver is still loaded while booting Safe Mode unless I misunderstood your description of the problem. What **might** work is loading the registry HIVE in another installation of Windows, removing the driver from appropriate key, and replacing the hive

Comment: I wouldn't do that without performing a backup of all registry hive files.

Comment: @Ramhound Could you explain how you recommend I edit the registry to prevent the driver from loading? I have a full raw backup of the disk already. Thanks!